# What natural numbers $k>2$ satisfy $k-2|2k$?

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, alternative-proof

> Find all positive integers $k>2$ such that $k-2|2k$.

I am stuck, I have tried everything. Also, I came up with an answer but I regarding the topics we are seeing currently in class I should be using modular arithmetic.

What I found was that $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \frac{2k}{k-2} = 2$. So, I should find the $k$ that causes $\frac{2k}{k-2} = 3$ which is $k = 6$ so $k \le 6$ and plugging in the integer values for $3 \le k \le 6$ I get $k = 3, 4, 6$.

The problem is that I think I should be using modulos and all that and I can't see how to do it that way.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} = 2$???

Comment: @barakmanos Why did you remove your answer? It's a good approach: you can conclude that $k-2\;|\;4$, hence $k-2\in\{1,2,4\}$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Because I noticed that the OP had already solved the problem, and was asking if there was an alternative "modular" approach.

Comment: @barakmanos Well, $a\;|\;b$ iff $b\equiv0 \pmod{a}$, so in some way it's still correct. And I feel it's how this question has to be solved anyway.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Got it, I'll undelete the answer if you think that it contributes :)

Comment: An approach consistent with yours, but perhaps having some sharper elements would be to note that your expression $r=\frac {2k}{k-2}$ is decreasing and greater than $2$ for positive integers $k>2$. Its maximum value of $r=6$ is attained for the minimum eligible value $k=3$ (because the value is decreasing), so you can try to solve for $r=5,4,3$ which are the only possible integer values. For this you don't need limits. However the method via divisibility is simpler and also eliminates more options more quickly.

Answer (score 5):

$\frac{2k}{k-2} = 2 + \frac{4}{k-2} \Rightarrow (k-2)|4 \Rightarrow k=3,4,6$.

There's no need to use limits or modules.

Answer (score 1):

First, $k-2|2(k-2) \implies k-2|2k-4$.

Therefore, $k-2|2k \implies k-2\leq4 \implies k \leq6$.

And for that, you've already got the solutions of $k=3,4,6$.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it modular, but it is it basically the same approach: $2k \equiv 0 \mod k-2$, so $4 \equiv 0 \mod k-2$, so $(k-2)\mid 4$. This again gives $k=3,4,6$.

Comment: How do you go from $2k \equiv 0 mod (k-2) $ to $4 \equiv 0 mod (k-2) $ ?